# Converting Days to Int SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, type-conversion

I have found many similar posts but for some reason I still cannot get my SQL script to work....

What I want to do is take the `DATEFIFF` between 2 dates and get the DAYS between the 2...

Then turn that into an `int` so I can do some simple math with it...

Here is what my code looks like...

```
'setting the vars
set @vendor = '%%'
set @sku = '%%'
set @startdate = '12-12-1900'
set @enddate = '12-12-2020'
set @dateDIFF =  DATEDIFF(DAY,@startdate,@enddate)

select 
    count(*) as [count]
    ,[inventory].[ParentSKU] 
    , @dateDIFF as [days left] 
    ,(sum([Inventory].[QOH]) -count(*)) * @datediff
    ,sum ([inventory].[QOH])
from 
    [order details]
join 
    [inventory] on [order details].[sku] = [inventory].[localsku]
where 
    [order details].[SKU] like @sku
    and [Order Details].[DateShipped] between @startdate and @enddate
    and [Inventory].[text1] like @vendor
group by 
    [Inventory].[ParentSKU]
order by 
    [count] desc
```

but no matter what I try I always get...

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: What is the type of `@dateDIFF`. It should [work fine](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155378)

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in your table and the variables?  Also, you should use ANSI standard notation for the date constants themselves (YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `datediff` expression is spanning more than a century, exactly 43830 days.

The largest integer is 2,147,483,647.  That means that when `(sum([Inventory].[QOH]) - count(*))` is greater than about 48,995 then you will get an arithmetic overflow.  My guess is that this is the problem.

You can fix this by doing the arithmetic in a floating point type or as `bigint`.